# nodejs i18n __ is not a function issue with ejs, express

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, underscore.js, ejs

I want to implement multi-language in my express (nodejs)
However I cannot understand why my ejs do not understand "__" underscore.

app.js

```
var i18n = require('./i18n');
app.use(i18n);
```

i18n.js

```
var i18n = require('i18n');

i18n.configure({
  locales:['fr', 'en'], 
  directory: __dirname + '/locales', 
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  cookie: 'lang'
});

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  i18n.init(req, res);
  res.locals.__ = res.__;
  var current_locale = i18n.getLocale();
  return next();
};
```

router.js

```
console.log(res.__('hello'));    // print ok
console.log(res.__('helloWithHTML')); // print ok

req.app.render('index', context, function(err, html) {
  res.writeHead('200', {'Content-Type':'text/html;charset=utf8'});  
  res.end(html);
});
```

/locales/en.json

```
{
  "hello": "Hello.",
  "helloWithHTML": "helloWithHTML."
}
```

index.ejs

```
<%= __("hello")%>
```

I got an error message for this:

```
__ is not defined at eval (eval at compile (/home/nodejs/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:618:12), :41:7) at returnedFn
```

However I can see the log message from router:

```
console.log(res.__('hello'));  // print out Hello
console.log(res.__('helloWithHTML')); // print out helloWithHTML
```

It works fine, I can see both `hello` and `helloWithHTML` values.

But `ejs` do not recognize `i18n` variable at all.

How can I resolve my issue?

Comment: For me it looks like your middleware is not needet. You can rewrite it like `module.export = i18n`, and then in app.js write `app.use(i18n.init);`, That's just to simplify it, i don't know where the problem with the current  code is.

Comment: @Starke If I put app.use(i18n.init) is the same result :( I need to figure out why this issue's happened to me. Strangely console.log(res.__('hello')) works fine so I think it is related to ejs or any else..

Comment: yeah i guess so too, `req.app.render('index')` looks a bit strange to me, usualy its just  `res.render('index');`

Comment: I usually used to render with middleware. I also set my app like this app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From docs:

> In general i18n has to be attached to the response object to let it's public api get accessible in your templates and methods. As of 0.4.0 i18n tries to do so internally via i18n.init, as if you were doing it in app.configure on your own

So, the simplest way you could use is:

```
// i18nHelper.js file <-- you may want to rename the file so it's different from node_modules file
var i18n = require('i18n');

i18n.configure({
  locales:['fr', 'en'], 
  directory: __dirname + '/locales', 
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  cookie: 'lang'
});
module.export = i18n

// app.js
const i18n = require('./i18nHelper.js');
app.use(i18n.init);
```

Or if you really want to bind (on your own):

```
// somei18n.js
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.__ = i18n.__;
  return next();
};

// app.js
const i18nHelper = require('./somei18n.js')
app.use(i18nHelper);

app.get('/somepath', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
})
```

Comment: Thank you but if I declare module.export = i18n directly I just saw error message about "TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function" So I have to write app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    i18n.init(req, res);
    next();
 });

Comment: not directly, I updated answer to reflect your example as well

Comment: Finally I solve my case. I change character set from ms949 to utf-8 en.json, fr.json then the result is fine. So I assume i18n's related to locales files sensitively. Anyway my issue just go away. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

i18n.js

```
var i18n = require('i18n');

i18n.configure({
  locales: ['zh_CN', 'en'],
  directory: __dirname+'/locales'
});

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  let {lang} = req.query;
  i18n.init(req, res);
  lang = lang ? lang : 'zh_CN';
  i18n.setLocale(req, lang);
  return next();
};
```

Other files are the same with you.

Hope to be helpful.